# Abline not fitting to barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm trying to ad an abline plot to a barplot grafic but the x-axis don't seem to fit.

So this is my code:

```
#Emotion im FB darstellen
y <- FB$Ärger[FB$Episode ==1] #Subset erstellen
data <- factor(y, levels = c(1:7)) #faktorisieren
table(data)
#barplot erstellen
barplot(table(data), 
        main = "E1 - Ärger", 
        xlab = "Rating", 
        ylab = "Häufigkeit",
        ylim = c(0, 8))

#w2v integrieren
abline(v=1,col="red")
abline(v=2,col="red")
abline(v=3,col="red")
abline(v=4,col="red")
abline(v=5,col="red")
abline(v=6,col="red")
abline(v=7,col="red")
abline(v=index(my.xts.data)[endpoints(my.xts.data, "days")]
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

Ideally abline(v=1) should show up in the center of the first bar and so one. 
But the scale of the abline x-axis seems to be shorter than the one of the barplot. 
Any ideas how I cold make both of them fit?

Thanks a lot!
Lorena

Comment: It's easier, if you provide some sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `barplot` automatically adds a space of 0.2 before each bar. This means you have two options. One is to get rid of the spaces, then subtract 0.5 from the value of each `abline` to make it match up to the centre of the bar:

```r
Rating <- factor(c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5), levels = 1:7)
barplot(table(Rating), 
        main = "E1 - Ärger", 
        xlab = "Rating", 
        ylab = "Häufigkeit", space = 0)
abline(v = seq(7) - 0.5, col = "red")
```

[image]

The other option is to leave the spaces by starting at 0.7 and incrementing by 1.2 for each bar:

```
barplot(table(Rating), 
        main = "E1 - Ärger", 
        xlab = "Rating", 
        ylab = "Häufigkeit")
abline(v = seq(0.7, 8, 1.2), col = "red")
```

[image]

To make this easier, you could define a function that does the calculation for you:

```
add_vlines <- function(x) abline(v = (x * 1.2) - 0.5, col = "red")
```

So you could just do:

```
add_vlines(1:7)
```

to get the lines you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, Allan! The last option is the best for me as it allows to ad abline plots for different x-values (which is what I want)